# Identify/translate this text

Tags: hebrew

Could anyone please identify this text, or translate it?

To put into context, it originates from some artwork displayed in a Freemason's Lodge.  I ask here as I *believe* it is Hebrew, and relates to King Solomon in some manner.

I have tried various OCR software to translate it, but the language is not recognised by them.

[image]

Apologies if I am incorrect, I did not mean to cause upset or offence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't explain the handwriting, but the words say "kodesh l'hashem" (Holy to God). There are 2 "boxes" which seem to be dividers though I'm not sure why there is one between the L and God's name (unless it is a printout from a font which can't handle vowel points).

Also, the dalet (D, second letter) in the first word looks more like a reish (R) and the vav in God's 4 letter name also looks like a reish. **Note -- the second box also replaces the missing yod**

For an explanation and source of the phrase, see [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/lifeline/5760/tetzaveh.html).

In brief, it was engraved on a headband which the High Priest wore.

Comment: Really interesting, thank you very much.  The accompanying link does actually fit what I was told the remainder of the illustration depicts (it's a hand painting, rather than printed font).

Comment: I only wonder if the person who painted it copied it from a print out which had a font problem.

Comment: That's another strong possibility as I know the author did not speak the language (or it is not documented at least).

Comment: I must be missing something in how you determined what this says. The boxes look like ending mem's. And I have no idea how you determined that the 2nd to last letter is a "shin" or that the whole thing is a reference to G-d's name.

Comment: @DanF the squares can't be final letters for 2 reasons -- one is that they appear after series of letters which don't constitute words and two, their upper corners are too sharp. The painter drew rounded edges for all the other letters, even those which have top "corners" (like the hey). The second to last letter is not a shin.